# Unable to ping computers via DNS domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller, windows-server-2012, ping, windows

I have two desktop computers and recently set up a third computer, a Windows Server 2012 box, for which I installed DNS on it and set it up as a domain controller. I was able to successfully set up each computer to be part of the new domain. There is a router, which goes to the outside world.

Issue:
I cannot ping the other computer via a fully qualified DNS domain name. I also set up an A-record, which neither computer can ping.

Domain: myoffice.com
Computers: ComputerA, ComputerB
Fully Qualified Names: ComputerA.myoffice.com and ComputerB.myoffice.com

Each computer can ping itself using the computer name or its fully qualified name. The server, however can ping either computer.

Each computer has the Primary DNS Gateway set to the server's IP address and the Secondary Gateway set to the router's IP address. The router provides all DHCP addresses.

I created a new A record in the DNS Manager in [DNS |  | Forward Lookup Zones | myoffice.com] setting mail.myoffice.com to the IP address of the server. Neither workstation can see the new A-record. I even did an "ipconfig /flushdns", not that that helped.

Obviously, I am not doing something that I should do. How do I troubleshoot the problem(s)?

Update:
Each client computer can ping the IP address of the domain control and by its computer name, just not the fully qualified domain name of the server.

Output of nslookup:
C:\Users\sarah>nslookup bvoffice.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758

*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for bvoffice.com

ComputerA IP Config Output

```
ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sarah-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : bvoffice.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : bvoffice.com

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2C-D0-5A-08-42-80
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-54-D2-7E-23-FB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4cad:f3e4:e472:b8c0:dfcb:ee45:c6a1(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2002:4cad:f3e4:e472:1dbe:3610:a70b:314d(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b8c0:dfcb:ee45:c6a1%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.9(Preferred)
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, July 3, 2013 12:56:23 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 5, 2013 2:29:40 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758%13
                                       192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 275797202
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-50-2E-76-70-54-D2-7E-23-FB
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758%13
                                       192.168.0.8
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D8E204FB-BED9-4124-A71F-4A787C17CC6B}:

           Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3c4e:1fb:b352:c1b(Preferred)
                   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c4e:1fb:b352:c1b%17(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Server IP Information

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : BvOffice-Server
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : bvoffice.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : bvoffice.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : .......
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4cad:f3e4:e472:191b:925d:194c:f862(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::191b:925d:194c:f862%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.8(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758%12
                                       192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 259027388
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-4E-EB-C4-70-71-BC-C2-87-67
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       192.168.0.1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F8DDE0EA-4905-44FC-A7AB-A2305032D53A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

ComputerB IP Information

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Eniko-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : bvoffice.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : bvoffice.com

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-26-82-75-A3-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : CC-52-AF-C8-ED-C1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : ..........
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4cad:f3e4:e472:c436:3a32:a4d5:2ab8(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2002:4cad:f3e4:e472:51de:2b58:ba08:d13d(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c436:3a32:a4d5:2ab8%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, June 30, 2013 8:47:01 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 5, 2013 2:52:38 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758%13
                                       192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 367028629
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-6A-5C-11-00-26-82-75-A3-06
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::224:b2ff:fe57:9758%13
                                       192.168.0.8
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros 802.11 a/b/g/n Dualband Wireless Network
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-26-82-75-A3-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0DD203E4-1E86-4994-A801-1475B5B30BAD}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3c67:19c3:3f57:fffb(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c67:19c3:3f57:fffb%18(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: I would first determine if the two client computers can ping the IP address of the domain controller.  Verify the client computers have the IP of the domain controller as their DNS resolver.  Try to run the command nslookup myoffice.com .  If the pings fail you have a network configuration problem not a DNS resolution problem.  Adding the output of ipconfig/all from all 3 computers would help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I don't know Windows tools well, but in Linux, I always use `dig` to query nameservers. I use `dig bla.com @ns1.domain.com` to query a specific nameserver. Can you use a tool like nslookup to query the nameserver and see if it responds?

Comment: I updated the question and included the answers / requests from the two comments.

Comment: Looks like you have both Teredo and 6to4 active. Unless you absolutely must have these, and can't get IPv6 any other way, you should disable both; and if you need one, only use one.

Comment: I disabled the two interfaces using netsh from an administrative command prompt. Maybe, it might even help network performance a bit.

Comment: Interesting, I now get "Server: UnKnown, ***** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for sarah-pC, when I use nslookup. The error is true for all computers now that I disabled those two interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

DNS settings are incorrect.  DNS IP's point to DNS servers, the terminology of "DNS gateways" is incorrect and misleading as DNS servers only respond to queries, they don't do any packet routing.

On Windows Server:
-In IPv4 TCP/IP properties change primary DNS server to 192.168.0.8 (no secondary DNS)
-Do an "ipconfig /registerDNS", reboot.

In DHCP server scope (currently this is the router):
-Change primary DNS server to be 192.168.0.8 (Windows Server IP)
-Do not use a secondary DNS server unless there is a 2nd AD DNS server on the LAN.

Note that w/ a Windows server in place then network browsing works better if DHCP is done on server & DDNS is enabled.  See:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771255.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#Function

Workstations:
Reboot or "ipconfig /renew" after above changes are completed.

Yes, if the Windows DNS server goes down then the internet is also down.  If that's the case then there will be larger issues and the DHCP scope on the router can be enabled at that time.

Because AD depends on DNS internal workstations should only use internal AD DNS servers.  Having an external 2ndary DNS will cause unpredictable browsing, logon and network performance issues in an AD domain.

Using a .com like BVOffice.com for an AD name is often problematic and not recommended IMO. Currently there are no public DNS records but if this is not your domain name then I would either buy it, but I would still change the internal AD name to bvoffice.local.  Using .com for an AD name can be managed (mostly...) but requires a good understanding of DNS and TCP/IP.

Comment: I made the first change on the server, however I am confused on the second change. There has to be the ISP's DNS server mentioned somewhere, otherwise no workstation or the server will be able to resolve an IP address. With the router pointing to the Windows Server and the Windows Server pointing nowhere but itself, how would any computer, server or workstation, resolve an address, say serverfault.com?

Comment: ISP's server is not required, the DC can and must provide DNS services.

Comment: Research the root hints file to understand why no DNS server is dependent on their ISP for DNS.

Comment: To add on Ed's comments: By default, all DNS Servers contain information about "root DNS servers" which provide hints on how to resolve _all_ public domain names. Active Directory DNS by default contacts one of these root servers for domains not explicitly handled by it. Accessing a root server, however, might be very slow; in this situation, you can configure AD DNS with "forwarders", i.e., servers that AD DNS will contact first before trying the root servers. If your ISP has a properly sized, reliable DNS server, then you can configure it as the forwarder server.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your clients have their DNS settings pointing to servers other than your domain controller.  I would recommend manually trying a lookup of a FQDN using a specified server.  like  `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` would use the DNS server 8.8.8.8 to lookup google.com.  Replace 8.8.8.8 with the IP of your domain controller and google.com with a FQDN on your domain.  If that works remove all other DNS client settings other than your DC.